# Unix/C: put a file into shared memory

Tags: c, file, memory, posix, shared

Have a problem.
I have a file which contents look like **number:error_description**.
Now i need to put this file **to shared memory (POSIX)**. If any contents are modified it should be **saved to the base-file**.
There is a need to search in the content in the shared memory (results will be sent to a client over a message queue).
How do I implement all this? First I thought I have to open **(fopen("my_file", "r"))** and then I have to create shared memory and mmap the file.
Can someone help me?

edit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
/*
 * \ /tmp/errors -> Error File
 */
#define MSGQ_HANDLER    "/error_handler"
#define PATH_TO_FILE    "/tmp/errors"
#define FILE_MODE (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)

int main(void) {

    int fd = open(PATH_TO_FILE, O_RDWR);
    struct stat file_stat;
    fstat(fd, &file_stat);
    printf("File size: %zd\n", file_stat.st_size);
    char *byte_ptr = mmap(NULL, file_stat.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                              MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if(byte_ptr == MAP_FAILED){
        perror("error:");
    }


    while(1){
        printf("%s\n", byte_ptr);
        if(byte_ptr)
            exit(1);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So far it is what I have now.
Read a line works.
How do I change the content?

Comment: Seems like you haven't tried anything yet. Give it a shot and ask here if you need help with something specific.

Comment: define "shared memory" and explain what you have already tried

Comment: @user1824407: [Shared memory](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) (unless OP has no idea what he's talking about).

Comment: Following to what is given in my task, I have to use shared memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `fopen` and forget about shared memory (the `sh*` API I mean). `mmap` is all that's needed.

Open your file with `open` and the right options (read/write). Then use `mmap` with the option `MAP_SHARED`. All changes in the file will be reflected directly and visible to all processes that map the same file. On Linux and Solaris (on other systems I don't know, but it is not guaranteed by POSIX or any standard) you can even access the file concurrently with `read`/`write`. It is a bad idea though.
Concurrent memory accesses from different processes will, of course, need synchronisation (mutex, semaphores etc.).

Comment: Instead of using memory mapping (mmap) is it possible to use shared memory?

Comment: So far, if I want to use shared memory, at first I need to open the file, create a new shared memory, and read each line of the file and write to the shared memory. Then I can write the whole shared memory (like write a line to file) to the file. Can it be made a little bit more simple?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how the POSIX `shm*` API could be included in your code. As far as I understand, `shm_open` is used to create a shared memory object, which is not much more than a kernel handled file with backup storage in the swap area. Memory mapping an existing file is not directly possible and would need copying the content from the regular file to the shared memory and back. Using `mmap` directly on the file is the way to go.

Comment: May be I'm missing something, as I really never used the `shm*` API in the real world. Except for some toy programs where I tested things, I never saw a practical usefulness of that API. If someone has ideas what it brings beyond what `mmap` can do alone, I'm interested.

Comment: In your program, I would open the `mmap` with `file_stat.st_size+1` as size. This will guarantee that there is always a 0 byte at the end, even if the file is a multiple of the page size. If your file was 4096 (on x86) bytes long, your `printf` would likely cause a segmentation fault.